# Using a key listener to stop a loop

Tags: python, listener, onclicklistener, python-keyboard

I'm trying to make python run a loop and when I press <kbd>Shift+a</kbd> the loop stops:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput import keyboard

COMBINATIONS =[
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
    ]

on = True
print(on)

mouse = Controller()
curent = set()

def execute():
    on = False
    pass

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        curent.add(key)
        if any(all(k in curent for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        curent.remove(key)


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listner:
    listner.join()

execute()

time.sleep(4)
while on == True:
    print('hi')
```

The problem is the code doesn't even get to the:

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listner:
    listner.join()
```

It stops if I put it after the `while True` loop the shortcut doesn't work, and if I put it inside the `while True` loop it pauses the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the add_hotkey method.
Here is an example:

```
import keyboard

on = True

def execute():
    on = False # The function you want to execute to stop the loop

keyboard.add_hotkey("shift+a", execute) # add the hotkey

while on:
    print("hi") # Do the code of your loop here
```