# how to make program stop with a hotkey (outside the console)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, mouse

I made an **autoclicker** and i can stop it by pressing *b* *but only at the right timing*. I didn't find anything that would allow me to stop the program by pressing a button **at any time without accessing the console**

Here's the program:

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard
import mouse

state=True
while state:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("b"):
        state=False
    else:
        mouse.click()
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a key listener to stop a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72422755/using-a-key-listener-to-stop-a-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered at [Using a key listener to stop a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72422755/using-a-key-listener-to-stop-a-loop/72422826#72422826)

You can simply use the `add_hotkey` method.
Example:

```
import keyboard

state = True

def stop():
    state  = False # The function you want to execute to stop the loop

keyboard.add_hotkey("b", stop) # add the hotkey
```